# Vuetify fab not rendering properly in Vue.js app hosted on Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuetify.js

I am hosting a Vue.js application on Firebase. The app uses Vuetify with the `fab` option in order to render some of the buttons as circles:

```
<v-btn
  class="blue lighten-2 mt-3"
  fab
  dark
>
  <v-icon>mdi-account-circle</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

When the app runs in localhost, the `fab` option renders properly:

[image]

However, when after running the app in Firebase hosting, the `fab` option does not render properly. The buttons instead end up looking like this:

[image]

I tried upgrading Vuetify in the app, but that did not work. Any idea why `fab` option in Vuetify does not render properly when hosting the app in Firebase?

Comment: What does the inspector show? Is the style/classes different from the Firebase vs Localhost?

Comment: There is no difference in classes between Firebase and localhost, according to the inspection tool.

Comment: Is the npm built ran properly, any error

Comment: no errors in the console

Comment: which version of vue and vuetify do you have